# Flex: select tree node right after the dataProvider is been assigned / updated / replace

Tags: apache-flex, tree

i have a Flex tree control and im trying to select a tree node 3 levels down right after the dataProvider is assigned with a collection object like the following.

basically treeItem1, treeItem2, treeItem3 are the nodes in the tree and treeitem3 is a child of treeItem2 which is a child of treeItem1. Assume these treeItem(1,2,3) are referenced correctly from the collection items.

my problem is that if i wait for the whole component to load completely then select the nodes, it open/select/scrolltoIndex correctly. However, if i were to select the node right after the dataProvider is assigned, then it doesn't even open or select (basically the *this.treeService.selectedItem* is always null).

can anyone point out what i did wrong? is there anything needs to happen after the dataProvider is assigned?

thanks

```
this.treeService.dataProvider = oPricingHelper.getCurrentPricingSercicesTreeSource();
this.treeService.expandItem(treeItem1, true);
this.treeService.expandItem(treeItem2, true);
this.treeService.selectedItem = treeItem3;
this.treeService.scrollToIndex(this.treeService.selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the updateComplete event to know when a component (such as a DataGroup or List) has completed rendering after performing a simple task (such as updating the dataProvider reference).  Of course, you have to be careful and remove listening to updateComplete because it can run a lot, unless you have a need for it to run.

Something like:

```
//...some function...
    this.treeService.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onTreeUpdateComplete);
    this.treeService.dataProvider = oPricingHelper.getCurrentPricingSercicesTreeSource();
//...rest of some function...

private function onTreeUpdateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
    this.treeService.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onTreeUpdateComplete);
    this.treeService.expandItem(treeItem1, true);
    this.treeService.expandItem(treeItem2, true);
    this.treeService.selectedItem = treeItem3;
    this.treeService.scrollToIndex(this.treeService.selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive your experiencing the same issue but I seem to have the same type of problem with using the advanced data grid, it appears in these cases where the dataprovider is acceptable as multiple types, the components do some extra work in the background to wrap things up into something Hierarchical (HierarchicalData or HierarchicalCollectionView) and in doing so the dataprovider setter call is not synchronous (so it will return before actually having assigned the internal property storing the dataprovider).  I've used callLater in this case with moderate success, callLater is generally a bad practice but basically adds a function to a list of functions to call once background processing is done, so this is assuming that something in the dataprovider setter called UIComponent.suspendBackgroundProcessing() and that it will subsequently call UIComponent.resumeBackgroundProcessing() and then it will execute the list of functions added by using callLater.  Alternatively you could use setTimeout(someFunction,1000).

These are both "hacks" the real solution is to dig into the framework code and see what it's really doing when you tell it to set the dataprovider.  Wherever you see that it actually has set the dataprovider you could extend that class and dispatch an event that you could listen for to run the function to do the selections after this point.

If anyone has a better solution please by all means correct me (I would love to have a better answer than this)